# UIScrollView moves down when I make exit from a popped view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a problem with navigation controller and 2 view controllers. When I pop to other view controller all is OK, but when I return to my first view it shows a **big white place under navigation bar**

On a second controller I have a keyboard automatically shows and hides when I edit UITextField.
This problem begins when I have returned from a second view controller where keyboard was shown.
Other way (no editing UITextField) I have no this problem with first controller.

What I need to do?

First .m file

```
#import "OTPTRecordViewController.h"
#import "OTPTAppDelegate.h"
#import "OTPTPractice.h"


@implementation OTPTRecordViewController
@synthesize scrollView, activeField;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];

    viewBackgroundTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:viewBackgroundTap];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    //I need it for correct view insets

    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;    
}

#pragma mark Textfields&Keyboard management

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender
{
    [nameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [lengthTextField resignFirstResponder];    
}

- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];    
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{    
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    if (([holdOutTextField isEditing]) || ([cyclesTextField isEditing])) {
        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height+50.0, 0.0);
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    }       

    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    //For scroll view moves
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
    CGPoint origin = activeField.frame.origin;
    origin.y -= scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-(aRect.size.height));
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = textField;
    [activeField setSelectedTextRange:[activeField textRangeFromPosition:activeField.beginningOfDocument toPosition:activeField.endOfDocument]];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = nil;    
}

@end
```

Second .m file

```
#import "OTPTSaveViewController.h"
#import "OTPTAppDelegate.h"
#import "OTPTRecordViewController.h"

@interface OTPTSaveViewController () {
    UIViewController *parentViewController;
}

@end

@implementation OTPTSaveViewController

@synthesize textField;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UITapGestureRecognizer *viewBackgroundTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundTap:)];
    viewBackgroundTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:viewBackgroundTap];
    parentViewController = [self presentingViewController];
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    //some saving
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)tf {
    [tf resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

I think this problem because of keyboard notifications that came from popped controller.
But when I add

```
[self unregisterForKeyboardNotifications];
```

to viewWillDisappear and make method

```
- (void) unregisterForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];    
}
```

it gives me no effect

Comment: What do you mean on 'pop to other view controller' and 'return to my first view'? You should provide more info, including some code.

Comment: show your code of both file of .m file.

Answer (score 0):

A new property was added to UIViewController as of iOS 7...

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets
```

Per the [Apple Docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)

> Default value is YES, which allows the view controller to adjust its scroll view insets in response to the screen areas consumed by the status bar, navigation bar, and toolbar or tab bar. Set to NO if you want to manage scroll view inset adjustments yourself, such as when there is more than one scroll view in the view hierarchy.

You may want to set this property to NO if you're managing insets manually, as this can interfere with what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in some sly way

I made a BOOL in AppDelegate named **isAfterSafe**, make it YES in second file:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    OTPTAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.isAfterSave = YES;
}
```

and use simple **if** in the first file

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{    
    OTPTAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    if (!appDelegate.isAfterSave) {
        NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
        CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

        if (([holdOutTextField isEditing]) || ([cyclesTextField isEditing])) {
            UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height+50.0, 0.0);
            scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
            scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
        }

        CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;

        aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
        CGPoint origin = activeField.frame.origin;
        origin.y -= scrollView.contentOffset.y;
        if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, origin) ) {
            CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-(aRect.size.height));
            [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else appDelegate.isAfterSave = NO;    
}
```

Of course, that is not a beautiful way, but it solved this problem